# Visual studio - invisible buttons textboxes etc

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm adding buttons, textboxes in windows phone app project but they are all invisible. When I test that app on phone it's all there.

Design window look like that something like that:

http://screenshooter.net/102168419/bdclmge

Seems it doesn't adding me screen on that phone?

Comment: Paste your Xaml code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved my problem but no1 would ever guess what was wrong. 
Visual have some bug that if i turn maximum performance mode on my laptop. It doesn't work but if im turning avarage usage mode it's working. Ridiculous situation... I would've never guessed it but my friend has the same problem he'was trying to repair it for 4 days.